# is it possible to train spacy to identify any random organization name

Tags: python, nlp, spacy

is it possible to identify in spacy as an entity any random organization name in any language

i tried the pretrained model of spacy to identify the organization names but  but it fails on some places eg Rama works at Remote software

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can update an existing statistical model with more data, or train a new model from scratch. You can find more details and documentation here:

- Training basics: https://spacy.io/usage/training#basics
- Training the named entity recognizer: https://spacy.io/usage/training#ner
- Training code examples: https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/tree/master/examples/training
- `spacy train` command: https://spacy.io/api/cli#train